# How do I make an object attract another object?

Tags: modifiers, objects, physics

I have a ball and a cube a bit above it. I want to make the cube attract the ball towards it. I am new to blender so how do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is: Create a floor, a cube, a ball. The cube and the floor are *Rigid Body*, *Type* > *Passive*. The ball is *Rigid Body*, *Type* > *Active*. Into the cube, create (<kbd>A</kbd>) a *Force Field > Force*. In the *Physics* tab, give it a *Strength* of - 100 or whatever negative value. Play the animation, the force field should attract the ball.

[image]